# Does C# have fixed width types?

Tags: c#

C++ has [fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) which guarantee that I get a certain width independent of which compiler I use (of course it has to support the correct C++ version).
I am wondering if C# has something similar, but the only thing I can find is [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(v=vs.120).aspx). What if Microsoft decides that a ushort will no longer be a System.Uint16, but something else?
Is this something that has already been considered? Since I can't find anything on this subject.

Comment: The sizes of the types are specified in the C# language specification (section 4.1.5), so MS would have to change the language specification first - it doesn't work the same way the C++ standard does

Comment: *What if Microsoft decides that a ushort will no longer be a System.Uint16, but something else?* Then they'd break a crap ton of code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `System.UInt16` is clearly a 16-bit unsigned integer. `System.Int32` is a 32-bit signed integer. And so on. These are pretty much as fixed width as possible. Besides, aliases such as `ushort` and `int` will never change, they are well-specified. Breaking changes in a language aren't unheard of, but they are unlikely to happen without an extremely good reason.

Comment: Yes, C#s integer types are *predominantly* fixed width. The exception is e.g. `IntPtr` which is *explicitly* designed to model something which depends on the runtime architecture.

Comment: You don't get 100% guarantee anywhere. C++ people could change uint16_t to be a 32b signed int, like C# people could change ushort and System.UInt16 to be a 32b signed int. But neither group is insane enough for that.

Comment: But ... mmm ... who cares? If you need to work with bits use types with sizes (Int16, Int32) otherwise use int, ushort and forget about the real size because ... size does not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were very different starting points of C++ and C# in this regard.

C++ started as C with some extra features and hence in this regard (where those extra features aren't directly relevant) its starting point is C's starting point. C was designed starting in 1969 when the hardware in general use covered a wide range of byte/character and word sizes (as they still do in many domains). Not having fixed-size types as the default was very useful to C's (and later C++'s) user. Because they increasingly also often needed to be able to reason about the size of a type the fixed-size typedefs were then added.

C# started for use in desktop and server environments where a byte was always going to be an octet, a character was never going to be assumed to be the same as a byte, and the natural word-size was always going to be either 32-bit with 64-bit arithmetic also supported or 64-bit with 32-bit also supported (it also had a requirement to offer a degree of COM-compatibility and that required types of certain sizes). The relatively–rarely-used `IntPtr` and the even more rarely-used `UIntPtr` filled the gap in the other direction of when matching natural word-size really was important.

It was also bound not to a variety of machine architectures as C was, but to a single virtual machine architecture, namely the stack-based virtual machine described by the Common Language Infrastructure. If a C# implementation comes out for an architecture very different to those in mind when it was developed, it will still happen by producing a CLI implementation, and it's there that the gaps would be bridged.

While both have spread into other uses from their starting points, both carry the legacy of their different origins. C#'s types aren't just predominantly fixed-width, but they are fixed-width by definition.

Of course, decades from now there will likely be some pressure to change in some way, but it's reasonable to assume that there would at the very least be an upgrade path to whatever that future C# is.